# WCF Serialization Return - Noob

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have an object which I serialize nicely into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<people xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" userID="AX12345">
  <group groupID="1234_ABCD">
    <person name="Name 0" id="0" /> 
    <person name="Name 1" id="1" /> 
    <person name="Name 2" id="2" /> 
    <person name="Name 3" id="3" /> 
  </group>
</people>
```

Which is returned as a string to this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "format/{format}/userid/{userid}/sessionkey/{sessionkey}")]
    string Get(string format,string userid,string sessionkey);
```

When I view the returned data this service, I get this.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <GetResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetResult>**&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;people xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" userID="123BOBBY"&gt;&lt;group groupID="1234_ABCD"&gt;&lt;person name="Name 0" id="0" /&gt;&lt;person name="Name 1" id="1" /&gt;&lt;person name="Name 2" id="2" /&gt;&lt;person name="Name 3" id="3" /&gt;&lt;/group&gt;&lt;/people&gt;</**GetResult>
    </GetResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And what I would like is this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <GetResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetResult>
        <people userID="AX12345">
          <group groupID="1234_ABCD">
            <person name="Name 0" id="0" /> 
            <person name="Name 1" id="1" /> 
            <person name="Name 2" id="2" />
            <person name="Name 3" id="3" /> 
          </group>
        </people>
      </GetResult>
    </GetResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am a beginner with all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the answer was fairly simple.

```
[XmlSerializerFormat]
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "format/{format}/userid/{userid}/sessionkey/{sessionkey}")]
string Get(string format,string userid,string sessionkey);
```

DataContractSerializer is the default serializer, and `[XmlSerializerFormat]` overrides the serialization.

In my classes I have added serialization attributes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Myapp
{
    [XmlRoot("people")]
    public class People
    {
        private string strUserID = "";
        private List<Group> lstGroup;

        public People()
        {
           lstGroup = new List<Group>(); 
        }

        [XmlAttribute("userID")]
        public string UserID
        {
            get { return strUserID; }
            set { strUserID = value; }
        }
        [XmlElement("group")]
        public List<Group> Group
        {
            get { return lstGroup; }
            set { lstGroup = value; }
        }

     }
}
```

While I am happy with the short term gain, I will be looking deeper into this to make sure I keep control of the output.

Thanks

P

Answer (score 2):

Instead of serializing the object you may try returning it directly from the method and leave WCF to handle serialization:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "format/{format}/userid/{userid}/sessionkey/{sessionkey}")]
YourObject Get(string format,string userid,string sessionkey);
```

Comment: Hi - and thanks for responding so quickly.

the reason I was trying to serialize is thet WCF wraps the returned object in it's own tagging scheme - it prefaces <a before all the data tags and also there seems to be no control of how a complex object properties are serialized, and no differentiation between XML attributes and elements.

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm - I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx

I'll check it out and post my findings - looks like it may work for me - 12 pages of bed-time reading ;)